# Symfony4.3 Uncaught Error: The route "xxxx" does not exist

Tags: php, symfony-4.3, fosjsroutingbundle

I have the problem for fosJsRouteBundle in symfony 4.3 i have error in console `Uncaught Error: The route "xxx" does not exist.`

```
Uncaught Error: The route "app_autocompleted" does not exist.
    at r.value (router.min.js:1)
    at r.value (router.min.js:1)
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (_search.js:12)
    at mightThrow (jquery.js:3557)
    at process (jquery.js:3625)
```

Router Controller

```
/**
 * @Route("/{_locale}/app_autocompleted", name="app_autocompleted", options={"expose": true})
 */
```

php bin/console fos:js-routing:debug

```
| Name                     | Method | Scheme | Host | Path 
| app_autocompleted.pl     | ANY    | ANY    | ANY  | /{_locale}/app_autocompleted                                 |
| app_autocompleted.en     | ANY    | ANY    | ANY  | /{_locale}/app_autocompleted
```

I search the solutions here but i don't find greate id and i think problem is with this https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-4-1-internationalized-routing

Comment: I have the same problem. how did you solve it?